# Different img src for pikachoose carousel

Tags: javascript

I have a pikachoose script installed and working properly but I need to have the thumbs named in this form: imagename-100x120.jpg

Currently the script takes the src of  which lies in the html code and makes the thumbs from it so it looks like this:

```
<li><a href="#"><img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="" /></a></li>'
```

and script generates the thumbs with exactly the same src as above.

But I really do need the thumbs to have url like: images/image1-100x120.jpg.
I am making thumbs by separate script so I dont want to pikachoose generate them, I just want to pikachoose skip the generating part and only place the src="images/image1-100x120.jpg" as a source.

Full version of pikachoose is here: https://github.com/jeremyfry/PikaChoose/blob/master/lib/jquery.pikachoose.full.js

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

By adding a reference property to your image tags, pikachoose will skip creating thumbnails and you can use your own:

```
<img src="images/image1-100x120.jpg" ref="images/image1-original.jpg" >
```

Check http://pikachoose.com/versions/ for this and more options.